# Auto saving attachments with a specific extension

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to auto archive specific files attached to emails, like pdfs or Word files.

This is what I wrote:

```
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment>
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "I:\Folder"
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xlsm") Or InStr(objArr.DisplayName, ".pdf") Or InStr(objArr.DisplayName, ".docx") Then
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
    End If
    Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

I get a run-time error:

```
'424': object required
```

On the if clause.

Comment: Think Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment> should be Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachments. Changing the > to a s. Or maybe without the s.

Comment: Syntax and spelling while coding is essential - not something you can just throw together and hope it's understood.  So - `objAtt` or `objArr` throughout as @Jordan Biddlecombe has pointed out.  Also - an IF statement is looking for either a TRUE or FALSE result `InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xlsm")` will return the position of ".xlsm" within the displayname which isn't a TRUE or FALSE.  It returns a 0 if ".xlsm" isn't in the displayname - so ask if it's different from 0: `InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xlsm")<>0` returns TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

On the if clause you have used `objArr` for the `InStr` function for .pdf and .docx instead of `objAtt`.

Hopefully after you change these it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
Sub OpenAndSave()
    Const SAVE_TO_FOLDER = "\\192.168.1.10\STL_LogShare\TO KHAI STL\old\00 TK NHAP\"
    Dim olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem, intCount As Integer
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    
    intCount = 1
    For Each olkMsg In Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        strDate = Format(olkMsg.ReceivedTime, "yymmdd hhmm - ")
        olkMsg.Display
        
        For Each objAtt In olkMsg.Attachments
           If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".pdf") _
           Or InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xlsx") _
           Or InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xls") _
           Or InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xlsm") _
           Or InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".doc") _
          Or InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".docx") Then
         objAtt.SaveAsFile SAVE_TO_FOLDER & "\" & RemoveIllegalCharacters(objAtt.DisplayName)
        olkMsg.Close olDiscard
           End If
        Next
    Next
    Set olkMsg = Nothing
End Sub

Function RemoveIllegalCharacters(strValue As String) As String
    ' Purpose: Remove characters that cannot be in a filename from a string.'
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = strValue
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "<", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, ">", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, ":", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, Chr(34), "'")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "/", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "\", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "|", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "?", "")
    RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "*", "")
End Function

'--> Function to remove some text special characters
```

Comment: Notice: case-insentive, ex: ".PDF" -> you should add more extension if you want

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).